# Is there something I can do with the rings/amulets I'm not using?

Tags: path-of-exile

I have tons of rings and amulets that I don't use.

Is there some kind of transmutation (i.e. combining rings/amulets somehow), some gem to make them unique or something that I can do with these?

Here's a lightshot:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a few vendor recipes about trinkets such as rings and amulets [here](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Vendor_recipes#Equipment).

And here is a list of everything that has to do with rings and amulets, taken from mentioned link.

---

### **Full rare sets**

*These recipes require a full set of rare items. A full set is capable of filling all item slots in the inventory screen (not including flasks or the alternate weapon set). Specifically, it consists of:*

- *One of the following:*

  - Two-Handed Weapon ×1
  - One-Handed Weapon ×1 and Shield ×1
  - One-Handed Weapon ×2
- Helmet ×1
- Body Armour ×1
- Gloves ×1
- Boots ×1
- Belt ×1
- Amulet ×1
- Ring ×2

---

```
  Reward/Level of lowest-level item
  1 Orb of Chance/1 to 59
  2 Orbs of Chance/1 to 59, all unidentified OR all 20% quality
  3 Orbs of Chance/1 to 59, all unidentified AND all 20% quality
  1 Chaos Orb/60 to 74
  2 Chaos Orbs/60 to 74, all unidentified OR all 20% quality
  3 Chaos Orbs/60 to 74, all unidentified AND all 20% quality
  1 Regal Orb/75 to 100
  2 Regal Orbs/75 to 100, all unidentified OR all 20% quality
  3 Regal Orbs/75 to 100, all unidentified AND all 20% quality
```

---

## Vendor recipes involving rings & amulets

*Unless otherwise stated, the item level and rarity of the item produced are both equal to the lowest item level and rarity among all items required for the recipe.*

```
  1 Iron ring + 1 Red skill gem = 1 Ruby ring (white)
  1 Iron ring + 1 Green skill gem = 1 Topaz ring (white)
  1 Iron ring + 1 Blue skill gem = 1 Sapphire ring (white)
  1 Two-stone ring of each combo (3 total) = 1 Prismatic ring (white)
  7 Iron rings + 1 Coral ring (rare) = 1 Coral amulet (rare)
  7 Iron rings + 1 Paua ring (rare) = 1 Paua amulet (rare)
  1 Amulet (any) + 3 skill gems (1 of each color) = 1 onyx amulet
  1 Amber amulet + 1 Lapis amulet + 1 Orb of Transmutation = 1 Agate amulet
  1 Jade amulet + 1 Lapis amulet + 1 Orb of Transmutation = 1 Turquoise amulet
  1 Amber amulet + 1 Jade amulet + 1 Orb of Transmutation = 1 Citrine amulet
  5 magic items of same type = 1 new magic item of same type (*Item level of resulting item equals lowest item level among components*)
```

---

## Crafting!

*The following vendor recipes add or remove modifiers on items*

```
Ring or Amulet + Orb of Augmentation + Amnethyst flask = Ring or amulet with +x% Chaos Resist
Magic Wand x1 + Ruby/Sapphire/Topaz ring + Orb of Alteration = Wand with +1 to level of Lightning/Fire/Cold (depending on resist of ring used in crafting) Gems in this item x1
```

---

## Changing bandit rewards

*It is possible to change your Bandit choice. To do this, execute one of the following Vendor Recipes on the preferred Difficulty.*

```
20 Orbs of Regret + 1 Amber Amulet = Book of Reform (Oak)
20 Orbs of Regret + 1 Jade Amulet = Book of Reform (Kraitlyn)
20 Orbs of Regret + 1 Lapis Amulet = Book of Reform (Alira)
20 Orbs of Regret + 1 Onyx Amulet = Book of Reform (Eramir (skill point))
```

Comment: Take my well earned upvote!

Comment: `5 magic items of same type = 1 new magic item of same type` deserves highlighting.

Comment: @Sjoerd Can't do it in the grey square, unfortunately, and I'm too bad and too lazy to format it ~properly~

Comment: @user1337 If you looked who asked the question you would've noticed that that was not me, so I can't accept it.

Answer (score 4):

One notable example - if you have 60 unique rings, you can craft them into a [Loreweave](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Loreweave).